# Use previous value in MySQL to compute the next field?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to use previous values in MySQL to compute the next value? I couldn't explain what I mean more clearly in my poor English (anyone can understand what I asked by seeing the title of this post?), so let me explain it in a snippet:

```
select
year_id,
sum(case when event_cd >= 20 then 1 else 0 end) as h,
sum(case when ab_fl = "T" then 1 else 0 end) as ab,
h/ab as ba
from events
group by year_id
```

in the above snippet, when you run the query you will get the error, since there are no such columns in `events` table as `h` or `ab`. However, I want to use `h` and `ab` which are computed in the previous `sum(case when ~)` syntax. I remember there are some sort of ways to make it possible, but I don't remember how to do nor as I said, I couldn't find any relevant posts to meet what I'm asking due to my poor English, though since I'm sure this question is already posted here at SO, it's quite helpful even if you just link it with no detailed explanation.

Thanks.

[Update]

Thanks for the answers. I just wanted to use previous values in order to avoid subqueries and hence lots of redundant typing, and make the entire code more readable. I've used either methods (subqueries or write the entire syntax twice just to compute another value) as described by Mosty Mostacho, and if this is not feasible or pretty risky to use in MySQL, I can surely accept those two methods above. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways in MySQL (BTW, I've simplified the query a bit but it is still legal):

**Option #1: Expand the variables**

```
SELECT
  year_id,
  SUM(event_cd >= 20) h,
  SUM(ab_fl = "T") ab,
  SUM(event_cd >= 20) / SUM(ab_fl = "T") ba
FROM events
GROUP BY year_id
```

**Option #2: Use a derived table**

```
SELECT year_id, h, ab, h / ab ba FROM (
    SELECT
      year_id,
      SUM(event_cd >= 20) h,
      SUM(ab_fl = "T") ab
    FROM events
    GROUP BY year_id
) s
```

You might be tempted to think that the second will run faster but it is not the case. The first one is most likely to run faster because it doesn't need a derived table and can solve the issue in just one pass.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I just want to write it out like what I said in my original post. I know both of those two options and have used it in numerous times. However, with you and fancyPants answer above, now I'm not sure what I read was on MySQL... Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * h/ab as ba from 
(
select
year_id,
sum(case when event_cd >= 20 then 1 else 0 end) as h,
sum(case when ab_fl = "T" then 1 else 0 end) as ab,
from events
group by year_id)
source
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I meant I want to write it out in only one query (no subquery).

Comment: select
year_id,
sum(case when event_cd >= 20 then 1 else 0 end) as h,
sum(case when ab_fl = "T" then 1 else 0 end) as ab,
sum(case when event_cd >= 20 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(case when ab_fl = "T" then 1 else 0 end) as ba
from events
group by year_id

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
As @MostyMostacho explains in the comment below, this is **not an advisable technique**, due to the order of evaluation of user variable being undefined.

---

You can write a query using a MySQL variable using the syntax `@varname := 'value'` to store your sums in, and then reference that.

```
SELECT
  year_id
, @h := SUM(CASE WHEN event_cd >= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS h
, @ab := SUM(CASE WHEN ab_fl = "T" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ab
, @h/@ab AS ba
FROM events
GROUP BY year_id
```

Comment: According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html): `the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined`. It is risky to rely on that.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I ran this query with one more `group by` category, such as `group by year_id, bat_id`, it returned every record has exactly the same value. So how to use more than one group?

Comment: @MostyMostacho thanks, I've updated my answer to reflect that. user2360798 sorry, it looks like this method isn't going to work for you.