# mysql Unknown column 'friend_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a little error while doing query.

It says: `Unknown column 'friend_id' in 'on clause'`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE friends.user_id_1 
            WHEN 1 THEN friends.user_id_2 
            ELSE friends.user_id_1 
       END AS friend_id,
       friends.created
       /*users.name_surname,
       users.avatar*/
FROM friends
JOIN users ON friend_id = users.id
WHERE 1 IN (friends.user_id_1, friends.user_id_2) /*AND friends.status = 1*/
```

Problem obviously is `friend_id`, as it is not a real column. How do I fix error?

Comment: can you replicate the data and the query at http://www.sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use previous value in MySQL to compute the next field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686669/use-previous-value-in-mysql-to-compute-the-next-field). In short: You can't reference a column alias in a `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` happens *after* the join, so the alias cannot be used.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   friends.friend_id,
   friends.created
   /*users.name_surname,
   users.avatar*/
FROM (
    SELECT created,
        CASE user_id_1 WHEN 1 THEN user_id_2 
            ELSE user_id_1 
        END AS friend_id
    FROM friends
    WHERE 1 IN (user_id_1, user_id_2) /*AND status = 1*/
) friends
JOIN users ON friends.friend_id = users.id
```